# Session Variable with ajax seems empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, oop

I have a piece of code which is giving me trouble.
I am trying to get order values from a php class function :

```
public function generalSettings(){


    $totalprijs = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $value){
        $products->setProduct($key);
        $totalprijs = $totalprijs + ($products->prijs_exBTW * $value);
    }


    $inclbtw = ($totalprijs * ('1.'.$this->BTWPercnt));
    if($totalprijs > $this->franco_vanaf){
        $verzendkosten = 0;
    }else{
        $verzendkosten = $this->verzendkosten;
    }

    $btw = ($totalprijs + $verzendkosten) * ('0.'.$this->BTWPercnt);

    if($totalprijs > $this->franco_vanaf){
        $totaalInc = ($totalprijs + $btw);
    }else{
        $totaalInc = ($totalprijs + $btw + $this->verzendkosten);
    }

    $return = array(
        "subtotaal" => $totalprijs,
        "btw" => $btw, 
        "inclbtw" => $inclbtw,
        "verzendkosten" => $verzendkosten,
        "totaalInc" => $totaalInc
    );
    return($return);    
}
```

When I access this function from within the class it works. 

And when I call other function that uses this function in my checkout it works.

But when I try to access it in my AJAX-handling file it says:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

The code,when I call the function in the ajax file is as below:

```
if($isValid == true){
    unset($notneeded);
    $notneeded = array("ww1","ww2","huisnr","vhuis","companyvat","companyname","tel","firstname","lastname");
    foreach($_POST['gegevens'] as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($key,$verplichtArray) && (!in_array($key,$notneeded))){ 
            $fields .= "`".$key."`,";
            $values .= "'".$value."',";
        }
    }
    $shoppingcar = new Winkelwagen;
    $order = $shoppingcar->generalSettings();

    $fields .= '`timestamp`,`klant`,`totaal`,`totaalInc`,`verzendkosten`,`status`,`betaalmethode`';
    $values .= "now(),'".$acc->id."','".$order['subtotaal']."','".$order['totaalInc']."','".$order['verzendkosten']."','3','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['betaalwijze'])."'";

    if(isset($_POST['gegevens']['V'])){
        $fields .= ',`V`';
        $values .= ",'X'";
    }

    $message = "INSERT INTO order (".$fields.") VALUES (".$values.")";
}
```

It seems like when I call the function from the ajax file the session's empty 
but when I call the function from the file where I call to the ajax file it works just fine.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong???

**EDIT**

The piece of jquery i use to call the ajax file as requested:

```
$('#afrekenen').click(function(){
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            var fields = $('.addressform :input');
            $.each(fields, function(field,val){
                $(val).removeClass('errorInput');
            })
            var gegevens = {};
            var adresform = $('.addressform').serializeArray();
            $.each(adresform, function(index, val){
                gegevens[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            if(!$('input[name=payment]:checked').val()){
                var betaalwijze = 0;
            }else{
                var betaalwijze = $('.betaalwijze').val();
            }

            var voorwaarden = $('input[name=voorwaarden]:checked').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/inc/afrekenen.php',
                data: {"gegevens":gegevens ,"betaalwijze":betaalwijze,"voorwaarden":voorwaarden},
                success: function(data) {
                    response = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                    if(response.isValid == false){

                        $('#errormsg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'
                        +response.message+'</div>');

                        $.each(response.fouteVelden, function(index, object){
                            $('#'+object+'').addClass('errorInput');
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#errormsg').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'
                        +response.message+'</div>');
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

if have the 
ob_start(); tag and the session_start(); tag

also only the sessions that are somehow linked to my class are returning 1 when i try to print_r them the rest of my sessions still remain

the foreach through the $_SESSION['item'] in the first part of my code isn't working 
all the other parts of code work

**EDIT**

A good nights sleep seems to have solved the conflict... 
don't know what the error was and don't know how i fixed it but it works! 
Thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: print_r($_POST['gegevens']); seems to be null

Comment: How do you call the ajax? Any difference in domain.com and www.domain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that my sessions where saved in

```
session_save_path('../tmp');
```

added this to the top of my ajax file and it worked it's magic

Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

if /inc/afrekenen.php is in the same domain as your class then session is shared
and phpsid cookie is passed along your ajax request.
  In this case, the only problem would your session not being started in /inc/afrekenen.php.

Verify that session is started in /inc/afrekenen.php.

Comment: The Session is started

Answer (score 0):

```
// print $_POST['gegevens'] if it is returning you a json string so
// do this

$postDataGegevens = json_decode($_POST['gegevens']);

// if $postDataGegevens in current format 
// then pass in foreach

foreach($postDataGegevens as $key => $value){ 
    // your code here ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that part of the code is working.. the foreach through the $_SESSION['item'] in the first part of my code isn't working

Comment: Did you initialize yoour session in your class file. "session_start()"

Comment: i didn't in my classfile is this neccesary?